# How Can I save multiple records in same meta key?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-meta, meta-query

I want to save multiple dates in meta key.

I have a three dates 2,3,4 and I want to save all these values in same meta key but as a different values.

For example:

```
dates(meta key) 2(meta value)
dates(meta key) 3(meta value)
dates(meta key) 4(meta value)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work out of the box, as long as the "unique" parameter of [`add_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/) is `false`.

```
add_post_meta($id, '_dates', 2, false);
add_post_meta($id, '_dates', 3, false);
add_post_meta($id, '_dates', 4, false);
```

then somewhere else

```
$dates = get_post_meta($id, '_dates', false);
```

Now `$dates` should be an array of your 3 values.